# Implementing Request/Response interaction in Node-RED

Tags: node.js, node-red

In my current project, we are trying to implement a functionality using Node-RED for experiments and exploring new technologies.

The functionality is shown as follows. Here, the `BadgeReader` publishes its data using `publish-subscribe` to `Proximity`(it can be easily implemented using `MQTT` in `Node-Red`). The `Proximity` component receives data from `BadgeReader` and using that data it interact with `ProfileDB` using `request/response` interaction mode. Now, my question is--- how can we implmement request/response interaction in Node-RED? (Note that - Request/Response can be implemented using MQTT, but this question is related to dedicated request-response functionality in Node-RED?)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the available database nodes will allow you to send a query and receive a reply before moving on to the next node in the flow.

There is also the http-request node that will do the same for a HTTP call to a remote service.

You can't do this with the Node-RED MQTT nodes because they either start a flow or end a flow. MQTT is asynchronous and publishers should be totally decoupled from subscribers so there is no way to know if a message ever reaches a subscriber, so no way to handle error cases or time outs properly. While it is possible to do request/response with MQTT it is not best suited this task.

If you want to do this with MQTT or something else then you may have to look at writing your own node, there is no generic request/response capabilities built into Node-RED.

P.S. given your flow of questions over the last few days you should probably look at the Node-RED mailing list here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

It will be better suited to answering your questions than Stack Overflow